# Generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) for AWS Key Management Service (KMS) for Entrust Certificate Pickup

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, code-signing, amazon-kms

I am using Entrust to generate a code signing certificate for a C# .Net project. Entrust requires us to use Amazon KMS or CloudHSM to securely store the certificate and private key, but I cannot figure out how to create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) for AWS Key Management Service (KMS) for Entrust Certificate Pickup. We want to use Amazon KMS to store the code signing cert and private key for use in our build server and CI/CD pipeline. We do not want to use CloudHSM because of the costs compared with simply using KMS.

I searched their documentation and was unable to find any details. After talking to support, it sounds like this is a new requirement, and their knowledgebase is not yet updated. Looking through AWS knowledgebase, I can only find information on how to do this for CloudHSM.

I tried following the documentation in the link below as well, but it is for an SSL certificate and not a code signing certificate. I was able to generate a CSR and use that to pick up the CRT files and generate a PFK file to sign our .msi. However, the signature on the .msi does not properly validate, and Windows Defender still sees the installer as coming from and uknown author. https://www.entrust.com/knowledgebase/ssl/how-to-generate-certificate-signing-request-using-microsoft-management-console-mmc-on-windows-2012

Resulting signature in the .msi's file properties

[image: Resulting signature in the .msi's file properties]

Result upon running the installer

[image: Result upon running the installer]

Answer (score 0):

After some research and support calls with both Entrust and AWS, it seems like this approach is not fully supported. Although, Entrust technically supports using Amazon KMS to store the sign certificate, they do not have the documentation and/or support staff to actually be able to implement it. My guess is that they may have more documentation and support in the future, but right now, it does not really seem feasible to use Amazon KMS.

In the end, we ended up going with a different provider, DigiCert since they provide a fit for purpose, full end-to-end code signing solution for CI/CD pipelines. This includes securely hosting the signing cert and keys on their servers and providing CLI tools that we can use to extract those keys and sign our code in our pipeline. The documentation and tools were very straightforard and easy to follow, and we were able to implement this in a day.

Here is a link to the product we ended up going with: https://www.digicert.com/software-trust-manager